# how to copy several variable to columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements, copy-paste

I would like to copy several variable to columns.
I currently have data like this.

```
   date      bundle_name  totbund   prod1  totprod1  prod2  totprod2  
06/01/2019      a_bund       1        a       1        b       1
06/01/2019        a          1
06/01/2019        b          2
07/01/2019      b_bund       1        b       2
07/01/2019      b_bund       2        b       4
07/01/2019        b          2
```

to be like this

```
   date      bundle_name  totbund   prod1  totprod1  prod2  totprod2  
06/01/2019      a_bund       1        a       1        b       1
06/01/2019        a          1        a       1
06/01/2019        b          2        b       2
07/01/2019      b_bund       1        b       2
07/01/2019      b_bund       2        b       4
07/01/2019        b          2        b       2
```

So, I would like to copy data in bundle_name to prod1 and data in totbund to totprod1 if the prod1 and totprod1 columns of that row are empty.
Is there anyway to done this? Thanx so much in advance

Comment: I think [`ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/ifelse) will do what you ask. For instance, `with(dat, ifelse(is.na(prod1) | !nzchar(prod1), bundle_name, prod1))` and similarly for `totprod1`.

Comment: do you have any template to done this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "template". Does the code work for you?

Comment: what does !nzchar means?
can I do it with pipeline (i mean this one %>%)

Comment: [`?nzchar`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/nchar)

Comment: could I do this code with pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Direct use of `ifelse`:

```r
x$prod1 <- ifelse(is.na(x$prod1) | !nzchar(x$prod1), x$bundle_name, x$prod1)
x$totprod1 <- ifelse(is.na(x$totprod1) | !nzchar(x$totprod1), x$totbund, x$totprod1)

x
#         date bundle_name totbund prod1 totprod1 prod2 totprod2
# 1 06/01/2019      a_bund       1     a        1     b        1
# 2 06/01/2019           a       1     a        1             NA
# 3 06/01/2019           b       2     b        2             NA
# 4 07/01/2019      b_bund       1     b        2             NA
# 5 07/01/2019      b_bund       2     b        4             NA
# 6 07/01/2019           b       2     b        2             NA
```

Since you mentioned a pipeline (not sure which you mean):

**`dplyr`**

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  mutate(
    prod1 = if_else(is.na(prod1) | !nzchar(prod1), bundle_name, prod1),
    totprod1 = if_else(is.na(totprod1) | !nzchar(totprod1), totbund, totprod1)
  )
#         date bundle_name totbund prod1 totprod1 prod2 totprod2
# 1 06/01/2019      a_bund       1     a        1     b        1
# 2 06/01/2019           a       1     a        1             NA
# 3 06/01/2019           b       2     b        2             NA
# 4 07/01/2019      b_bund       1     b        2             NA
# 5 07/01/2019      b_bund       2     b        4             NA
# 6 07/01/2019           b       2     b        2             NA
```

**`data.table`**

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
xDT <- x
setDT(xDT)
xDT %>%
  .[, totprod1 := ifelse(is.na(totprod1) | !nzchar(totprod1), totbund, totprod1) ] %>%
  .[, prod1    := ifelse(is.na(prod1) | !nzchar(prod1), bundle_name, prod1) ] %>%
  .[]
#          date bundle_name totbund prod1 totprod1 prod2 totprod2
# 1: 06/01/2019      a_bund       1     a        1     b        1
# 2: 06/01/2019           a       1     a        1             NA
# 3: 06/01/2019           b       2     b        2             NA
# 4: 07/01/2019      b_bund       1     b        2             NA
# 5: 07/01/2019      b_bund       2     b        4             NA
# 6: 07/01/2019           b       2     b        2             NA
```

(The trailing `%>% .[]` is merely to get it to print on the console, unnecessary in production.)

---

Sample data. I added empty strings `""` to try to mimic what you have in your question, but I'm not certain if it looks that way because you actually have empty strings (and all numbers are really strings) or if you are just typing it in manually to make it look good. The `NA`s are inferred by R because the first row of data has numbers in it, and empty strings are not meaningful there.

```r
x <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text='
   date      bundle_name  totbund   prod1  totprod1  prod2  totprod2  
06/01/2019      a_bund       1        a       1        b       1
06/01/2019        a          1       ""      ""       ""      ""
06/01/2019        b          2       ""      ""       ""      ""
07/01/2019      b_bund       1        b       2       ""      ""
07/01/2019      b_bund       2        b       4       ""      ""
07/01/2019        b          2       ""      ""       ""      ""')
```

Comment: i found this error when I follow the code


"Error: `false` must be a character vector, not a double vector"
is there a miss?

Comment: That must be in the `dplyr` code, and is likely because I do not know what your data actually looks like. Realize that the 2nd/3rd arguments of `if_else` must be the same type, so if one is a string, the other must be as well (or it gives you this error). While you can almost-certainly fix the ***symptom*** with judicious use of `as.character`, that is masking the fact that you are likely trying to merge different data types. If you provide the output from `dput(head(x))` into your question, this discussion can be better-informed (and I might be able to give you a better answer).

Comment: BTW: this constraint in `dplyr::if_else` is not a factor in `base::ifelse`, and many (including myself) consider the constraint to be "*A Good Thing (tm)"*. Since the values are likely being assigned (as here) to a single column, if the "then" side returns a string and the "else" side returns a number, then all numbers will be converted to strings (as long as there is at least one "then"/true value. While "experienced programmers" try to make sure to do this manually, the fact that the function `if_else` errs when this constraint fails is considered "saving the programmer from themself".

Comment: is the 2nd argument bundle_name and prod1 for the 3rd argument?

Comment: I apologize if this sounds harsh, but have you read the documentation in [`?ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/ifelse)? The 1st argument "test" which is (or can be coerced to) a logical vector; the 2nd argument "yes" contains return values for true elements of "test"; and the 3rd argument "no" contains return values for false elements of "test". The returned value is *"... coerced from logical to accommodate first any values taken from 'yes' and then any values taken from 'no'"* (while `dplyr::if_else` allows no coercion).